# How do I develop app for the iPad mini

Tags: ipad, uilabel, xcode4.5, ipad-mini

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dealing with iPad Mini screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036745/dealing-with-ipad-mini-screen-size)

I want to develop app for the iPad Mini, and my app also should work on iPad but the iPad mini simulator doesn't come with the Xcode 4.5.

Is there any way I can see what my app is going to look like on the new iPad Mini ?

**I have One doubt.. Suppose i want my label in center of my iPad as well in iPad mini then how should i take care of that ?**

**For iPad,**

```
UILabel* label=[[UILabel alloc]init];
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
label.frame=CGRectFrame(350,200,20,20);
label.text=@"First ";
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

i can see my label will be in center..

but if i will run my same code in iPad mini then according to x position `350` my label will be at extreme right it will not be in center..

How take care of screen size in iPad mini as well iPad ?

**Any help will be appriciated.**

Comment: @H2CO3 how does one deploy without XCode? It's not equal.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato 1. Deployment is not the point, the answer to the **coding** question doesn't need the presence of Xcode. 2. I generally use SSH to copy the app binary to the device.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The iPad mini is the same (has the same screen resolution) as the iPad 1 and iPad 2. There is nothing different that you need to do to support the iPad mini.