# exclude iPad mini device Titanium iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, device, ipad-mini

I have created an iOS app in Titanium. I tried running the app on the simulators(6.1 and 5.1) and it works fine. However, when I run it on the iPad mini device it gets messed up.

Since, I have to submit the ap in the next 2-3 days; I ahve thought of excluding iPad mini from the app itself.

My app should not run on iPad mini. Is there a way to do that using XCode or Titanium.

Comment: Define "gets messed up". Does it work on an iPad 1 or 2? The mini has the same screen resolution as the iPad 1 and 2.

Comment: I tried running in the Titanium simulator with Display Non-Retina and iOS 6.1; it works fine over there. Are those simulator settings same as of iPad 2 ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Titanium but the iPad 1, iPad 2, and the current iPad minis all are 1024x768 non-retina devices. Keep in mind that testing on simulators is fine for general testing but you need real devices for real testing before submission.

Comment: [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13036781/874257) There is no difference between an iPad mini and iPad 2. If your app is not working on an iPad mini device, it wont work on any iPad 2 either.

Answer (score 0):

try to run your app on your ipad mini and make this code to get the ipad mini ID

```
Ti.API.info( Ti.Platform.model )
```

it should return's you the model of ipad... then you can make an `if` to know if the current device is a ipad mini or not... if it is you display a screen saying that the app isn't supported for ipad mini yet.