# Run app on iPad Mini Retina on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6

I build app for iPad and sent to my client, and gave me feedback that it runs on every iPad devices which we supported(**compatible with iOS5+ iPad 1G, 2G, 3G, 4G, mini, mini 2, Air**) except iPad Mini Retina, he said that App install fine but doesn't. I don't have iPad Mini Retina but I want to check this on my side. I install latest Xcode 6 but still I am not able to see iPad Mini Simulator which you can see attached image. So kindly any one give me suggestion how to accomplish this task. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

> Although an iPad mini isn’t an option for a simulated device in iOS
>   Simulator, you can still test apps for the iPad mini in the simulator.
>   To do this, run your app on the simulated iPad without Retina display.

via [Testing for the iPad mini](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html)

So, the scoop is that you have to build apps for iPad 2 resolution. The iPad Mini is non-retina with a resolution of 1024x768 which means apps that already worked on an iPad 2 automatically work on iPad Mini. This is another useful [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036745/dealing-with-ipad-mini-screen-size).

Answer (score 1):

You can test it on iPad Mini in Xcode by choosing **Resizable iPad** from the iOS simulators and then you can configure the pixel resolution in the simulator. The resolution in landscape is 1024x768 but on iPad Mini 2 and 3 it's 2048×1536. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html).

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 7 one should use Ipad 2 and iPad Air.
See the Reply from apple-staff-user "jeremyhu" on

```
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12567
```

i don't think thats an adequate solution although.

Comment: It is not, since iPad 2 didn't support multitasking, and iPad Mini 4 does; so, there's no way (at least, that I found) to test a multitasking app on an iPad Mini 4 in the Simulator.

Comment: @cdf1982 Just came to the same conclusion, which is how I found your comment. Did you file a bug on this?

Comment: @matt no, I didn't think about it, but I definitely should. I'll do it asap, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @cdf1982 Hang on a sec. Explain to me why iPad Air 2 simulator doesn't solve it? I think it's the same screen size as the mini 4...

Comment: @matt I don't see it as a resolution problem, my issue is that iPad Mini 4 app "size" when in multitasking is smaller that Air's

Comment: @cdf1982 Is it? In what sense? They are the same size screen, so 1/2 width or 2/3 width is the same on both. And the Air does full multitasking, so we can test.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right and I was wrong in my assumption that it would display differently! Thanks!